# iTunes Connect: reportingitc: autoingestion: Deprecated?

Tags: api, app-store-connect, analytics

For the past year, I have been pulling **iTunes Connect App Analytics** from this endpoint directly: **https://reportingitc.apple.com/autoingestion.tft**

**Is this endpoint soon to be deprecated?**

Because several of credentials I have been using to access this endpoint is now returning response:

*"Your username has access to more than one account. To use this feature please upgrade to Reporter. For more details, see Reporter guide in the Resources and Help section on iTunes Connect."*

What I need is endpoint point access to **iTune Connect App Analytics App Units**.

What API endpoint is now available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got that email 2 days ago:

[image]

Here's the link to `Reporter`:
https://help.apple.com/itc/appsreporterguide/#/itc0f2481229